# Can I mount electrical panel on exterior of bedroom?

Tags: electrical, mounting, exterior, bedroom

I am reading that the meter cannot be mounted on exterior of bedroom wall but what about the panel? This corner of house is a straight shot from the pole which is where the meter and a disconnect will be mounted.

Comment: Where did you find that? A service panel can be in any room other than a bathroom or a closet used for storing flammable (clothes  closet) out side only close to the gas meter is usually restricted.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading that meter is not to be on exterior of bedroom closet due to being close to combustibles. Wish I noted where I read it but thought it was a new requirement.

Comment: What combustibles? If it gets to clothing or bedding you have problems anyway. :)

Comment: It could be a utility-specific requirement.  Code may not care, but utilities are free to say "we'll only connect your house to our system IF...".  My utility, for example, wants the meter mounted within 3' of the corner of the building closest to their pole.

Comment: I have never seen a utility have a problem with any location other than a gas meter, they never enter the home they connect the service if overhead up at the weatherhead , underground on there side of the meter,.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility? Where are you reading that a meter is not allowed on the outside of a bedroom wall?

Comment: Highline Electric. Meter outside bedroom is not their requirement just something I read in searches.

Comment: Clothes closets are a no-go for panels.  Also, I’m told so are storage rooms in which we keep a stochiometric mixture of propane and pure oxygen, but that might have just my inspector being a jerk :)

Comment: Yeah this is an exterior wall mount thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An electric utility company may have rules about where they'll allow their service to be installed. For example, one electric utility I'm aware of will not connect service to a meter located within 36 inches of a window which has a view into restroom or sleeping areas. Near a garage window is fine; somewhere on a bedroom wall further than 36" from a window is also fine. It's obvious that this requirement has nothing to do with electric code. Instead, it protects privacy of building occupants and protects utility employees who may access the meter and disconnect at any time from compromising situations and ugly allegations.

An electric utility imposes their own rules on the service entrance as far as location, mounting, overhead or underground wiring, size of conduit for their service, etc. These rules are not in the National Electric Code; they're policies of the utility. Contact your utility to get a copy. It sounds like you may be working with second-hand information based on another person's inaccurate retelling of the utility's requirements.

Comment: Interesting. This is in a small town. They have not listed any requirements. They just said I should get inspected by someone (not them) for my safety. Prior meters were on house now they must be on pole and feeder buried to house panel. They don't want liability if meter burns up and takes house down is what he said is reason for change.

Comment: 2017 code requires the service disconnects to be outside usually located at the service.

Comment: @EdBeal -- correction, that change is 2020, not 2017 :)

Comment: @Jeff -- yeah, it seems many REA co-ops don't publish a detailed set of service rules.

Comment: You are right 3 phase I was answering other code related issues and was getting the dates scrambled but for a new service if the 20 code is adopted it would be relevant

Comment: @EdBeal yeah -- it's definitely something to plan for

Comment: @Jeff -- is it your town inspector that's saying the meter should be on a pole, or someone from the utility?

Comment: The utility wants the meter on a pole. They are going to do the pole, meter and disconnect all for free which is awesome. Town has no building permits or inspections but I prefer to do things to code to save hassles down the road.

Comment: @Jeff -- is the utility providing overhead or underground service?

Answer (score 0):

Service equipment disconnecting means 230.70.A

A1.Readily accessible outside or nearest point of entry.

A2.Bathrooms shall not be used.

A3. If remote controlled see A1

That’s it for service equipment nothing about bedrooms.

A service panel can be in (inside) any room other than a bathroom or a closet used for storing flammable (clothes  closet) out side only close to the gas meter is usually restricted. There are restrictions if an overhead feed the distance wires are from a window but the service can be mounted on an exterior bedroom wall unless local codes prevent it.

Edit added for inside;

240.24 are the inside locations

Comment: In my tract of 270 houses in Dallas some plans were built with the panel in a closet in the master bedroom. During renovation the panels are always moved to surface mounting on the exterior wall.

Comment: Wow , I think this has been code for over 30 years, I know once bathrooms were allowed as doing remodels I got inventive and Made a door to cover the panel that when opened blocked access to the bathroom, the inspector passed that and thought it was a great idea. The inspectors must not have been paying attention or your house is pre 70’s ?

Comment: Our tract was built in 1969 - 1970. I am under the impression that the moving of the panel from inside the clothes closet to surface mounted outside is required by Dallas electrical inspection. Luckily our plan has the panel inside an exterior wall of the garage.

Comment: I would have to go back to see if that was in my first code book that was the cycle before my apprenticeship when your home was built but it has been in code or not is storage closets with flammables for a long time.